# Is there a plugin for Visual Studio Code thats similar to GitGutter for Sublime text

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Im looking for a plugin thats the same as [GitGutter](https://github.com/jisaacks/GitGutter) (a Sublime Text) plugin.

I can't seem to see my changes in the gutter when I modify a file with the standard VS code version control git set up. Or am I missing a setting in the config for VS Code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I'm out of luck when it comes to that basic GitGutter Sublime text like plugin for VS code, but I found a really hardcode git plugin that does quite a lot more than I was initially looking for. So I guess Im going to use this for now.

The plugin is called [GitLens](https://gitlens.amod.io/). Hope this helps the next person thats stuck it in the same boat as me.

Answer (score 2):

VS Code gutter indicators for git is [supported out of the box](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_gutter-indicators). A couple of things to check:

- Ensure that the `scm.diffDecorations` setting is set to either `all` or `gutter`.
- Ensure that the `git.enabled` setting is set to `true`.
- Disable all extensions to see if one of them is causing it not to show in the gutter.

Comment: nothing is shown for me, is there a way to "compare against" a certain commit?